# Is there a way to show name from variable as parameter in php

Tags: php

I would like to get the name (not the value) of a paramter.
In the given case it should be $param.

```
function testfunc($param = 'i do not want this..', $array = array()) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    var_dump($args);
    echo $param; 
}
```

If I call the testfunc like this:

```
testfunc($testString,$testArray);
```

the result should be "$testString" ,"$testArray"

Is there a way in PHP?

Comment: This is not duplicated. Thats something else here.

Comment: The duplicates return the parameter names declared in the function signature. https://3v4l.org/oY24M  If you want to ignore the signature declarations and access the passed in variable names, why not pass them in as single quote wrapped strings? `'$testString'` and `'$testArray'`? What are you trying to achieve with this task?

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection

```
$myParams =  array_map( function( $parameter ) { return $parameter->name; }, (new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__))->getParameters() );
```

Thanks

Comment: Please flag duplicate questions instead of answering them.

Comment: [Very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175664/2943403)

Comment: I edited my question. 
not func_get_args(); 
not get_defined_vars(); 
not new ReflectionFunction; helps

Comment: thx @mickmackusa
the thing is that i do not wont the string parameter i wont: testString